# cannot access html element using selenium in python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web, element

I am tring to access a website, but when selenium open that website, a pop up appear and I don't know how to access the close button to close it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By # in the code there are usage of By but not imported
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver")
browser.get("https://fireant.vn/dashboard/content/industries/4000")
button=browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".bp3-button")
button.click()
```

I have tried to access css selector, xpath but it didn't work (I could not close the pop up)

Comment: You are looking for a class selector. Multiple elements can have this. Try to log and check if you are getting the element or not.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be

```
button=browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.bp3-button")
```

or

```
button=browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "bp3-button")
```

Comment: it didn't work:((

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, I have used the `xpath` and added the `WebDriverWait` for the element to be clickable.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver")

browser.get("https://fireant.vn/dashboard/content/industries/4000")

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
close_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//span[@class='bp3-icon bp3-icon-cross'])[5]")))

close_button.click()
```

Hope this will fix your problem...

Comment: it didn't work:((

Comment: Whats the `error` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By  # in the code there are usage of By but not imported

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver")
browser.get("https://fireant.vn/dashboard/content/industries/4000")
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
# Close First popup

button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[text()="Để sau"]')))
button.click()
```

If you want to close second one as well you can add

```
# Close second popup
secondButton = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[class*="bp3-dialog-close-button"] span[class*="bp3-icon bp3-icon-cross"]')))
secondButton.click()
```

Comment: it didn't work:((

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way:

```py
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

browser = Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)

browser.get("https://fireant.vn/dashboard/content/industries/4000")

buttons = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.bp3-button.bp3-minimal.bp3-dialog-close-button")))
buttons[1].click()
sleep(5)
```

Two things to note:

1. Use the correct selector
   `.bp3-button.bp3-minimal.bp3-dialog-close-button`
   instead of `.bp3-button`.
2. You'll notice that there are two such elements and you need to click the second (`buttons[1].click()`) as it is for the outer pop-up window which you're trying to close.